# Cannot GET data from Github API in Android Kotlin Development

Tags: android, kotlin, get, github-api

I am a beginner in Android development, I am experiencing problems when GET data from the GitHub API, I have a details page to display the details of the GitHub user but when I want to display the data it always doesn't work

the problem is that the details page can only display data once, after that the data cannot be loaded again because the value of the result is always `Result.Loading(false)`. This causes the application to have to be reopened every time you want to open the details page.

Can anyone help what makes `ResultViewModel.Loading` always have a value equals to false ? I need `ResultViewModel.Loading` to be true to update new data from the API.

Here is my code:

// DetailUserActivity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class DetailUserActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDetailUserBinding
    private val viewModel by viewModels<DetailUserViewModel>()

    private var isFavorite = false


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityDetailUserBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        val item = intent.getParcelableExtra<GithubUser.Item>("userItems")
        val username = item?.login ?: "User Not Found"

        Log.d("Intent berhasil", "Data berhasil diterima: $item")

        viewModel.getUser(username)

        viewModel.resultDetailUser.observe(this) { result ->
            when (result) {
                is ResultViewModel.Success<*> -> {
                    val data = result.data as GithubDetailUser
                    val user = data
                    binding.imageUser.load(user.avatar_url) {
                        transformations(CircleCropTransformation())
                    }
                    binding.fullNames.text = user.name
                    binding.username.text = user.login
                    binding.followerCount.text = user.followers.toString()
                    binding.followingCount.text = user.following.toString()
                    binding.repositoryCount.text = user.public_repos.toString()

                    Log.d("Detail User", "Detail User bisa di GET: $item")
                }

                is ResultViewModel.Error -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, result.exception.message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d("Intent Error", "Data gagal di GET")

                }
                is ResultViewModel.Loading -> {
                    binding.progressBar.isVisible = result.isLoading
                    Log.d("Loading Detail", "${result.isLoading}")
                }
            }
        }

        viewModel.getUser(username)
        val fragments = mutableListOf<Fragment>(
            UserFollower.newInstance(UserFollower.FOLLOWERS),
            UserFollower.newInstance(UserFollower.FOLLOWING)
        )
        val titleTabFragments = mutableListOf(
            getString(R.string.follower_tab), getString(R.string.following_tab)
        )
        val adapter = DetailUserAdapter(this, fragments)
        binding.viewPager.adapter = adapter

        TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabLayout, binding.viewPager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = titleTabFragments[position]
        }.attach()

        binding.tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                if (tab?.position == 0) {
                    viewModel.getFollowerUser(username)
                } else {
                    viewModel.getFollowingUser(username)
                }
            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
            }

            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
            }

        })

        viewModel.getFollowerUser(username)

        viewModel.resultFavoriteAdd.observe(this) {
            updateFavoriteButtonColor(true)
        }
        viewModel.resultFavoriteDelete.observe(this) {
            updateFavoriteButtonColor(false)
        }

        viewModel.findById(item?.id ?: 0) {
            viewModel.viewModelScope.launch {
                updateFavoriteButtonColor(true )
            }
        }

        binding.favoriteButton.setOnClickListener {
            val titleAdd = getString(R.string.notif_title_add)
            val titleDelete = getString(R.string.notif_title_delete)
            val addMessage = getString(R.string.notif_add_message)
            val deleteMessage = getString(R.string.notif_delete_message)
            val userId = item
            if (userId != null) {
                viewModel.viewModelScope.launch {
                    if (viewModel.isFavorite.value == true) {
                        Log.d("DetailUserActivity", "isFavorite: $isFavorite")
                        viewModel.delete(userId)
//                        viewModel.setFavorite(isFavorite)
                        updateFavoriteButtonColor(isFavorite)
                        sendNotif(titleDelete, deleteMessage)
                        Log.d("DetailUserActivity", "User dengan ID $userId dihapus dari favorit.")
                    } else {
                        viewModel.insert(userId)
//                        viewModel.setFavorite(!isFavorite)
                        updateFavoriteButtonColor(!isFavorite)
                        Log.d("DetailUserActivity", "User dengan ID $userId ditambah ke favorit.")
                        sendNotif(titleAdd, addMessage)
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    private fun updateFavoriteButtonColor(isFavorite: Boolean) {
        val colorRes = if (isFavorite) R.color.colorFav else android.R.color.white
        val color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorRes)
        binding.favoriteButton.setColorFilter(color)
    }


    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                finish()
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

// DetailUserViewModel

```
    @HiltViewModel
    class DetailUserViewModel @Inject constructor(
        private val repository: GithubUserRepositoryImpl,
    ) : ViewModel() {

        val resultDetailUser = MutableLiveData<ResultViewModel>()
        val resultFavoriteAdd = MutableLiveData<ResultViewModel>()
        val resultFavoriteDelete = MutableLiveData<ResultViewModel>()

        val resultFollowersUser = MutableLiveData<ResultViewModel>()
        val resultFollowingUser = MutableLiveData<ResultViewModel>()


        fun getUser(username: String) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                flow {
                    val response = repository.getDetailUserFromGithub(username)
                    resultDetailUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(true)
                    emit(response)
                }.onCompletion {
                    resultDetailUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(false)
                } .catch {
                    Log.e("Error ", it.message.toString())
                    it.printStackTrace()
                    resultDetailUser.value = ResultViewModel.Error(it)
                } .collect {
                    // Ubah tipe data yang dikirimkan ke resultSuccess.value
                    resultDetailUser.value = ResultViewModel.Success(it)

                }
            }
        }

        fun getFollowerUser(username: String) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                flow {
                    resultFollowersUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(true)
                    val response = repository.getFollowerUserFromGithub(username)
                    emit(response)
                } .onStart {
                    resultFollowersUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(true)
                } .onCompletion {
                    resultFollowersUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(false)
                } .catch {
                    Log.e("Error ", it.message.toString())
                    it.printStackTrace()
                    resultFollowersUser.value = ResultViewModel.Error(it)
                } .collect {
                    // Ubah tipe data yang dikirimkan ke resultSuccess.value
                    resultFollowersUser.value = ResultViewModel.Success(it)
                }
            }
        }

        fun getFollowingUser(username: String) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                flow {
                    resultFollowingUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(true)
                    val response = getFollowingUser(username)
                    emit(response)
                } .onStart {
                    resultFollowingUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(true)
                } .onCompletion {
                    resultFollowingUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(false)
                } .catch {
                    Log.e("Error ", it.message.toString())
                    it.printStackTrace()
                    resultFollowingUser.value = ResultViewModel.Error(it)
                } .collect {
                    // Ubah tipe data yang dikirimkan ke resultSuccess.value
                    resultFollowingUser.value = ResultViewModel.Success(it)
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

// ResultViewModel

```
sealed class ResultViewModel {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : ResultViewModel()
    data class Error(val exception: Throwable) : ResultViewModel()
    data class Loading(val isLoading: Boolean) : ResultViewModel()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun getUser(username: String) {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                resultDetailUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(true)
                    flow {
                        val response = repository.getDetailUserFromGithub(username)
                       emit(response)
                    }.onCompletion {
                        resultDetailUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(false)
                    } .catch {
                        Log.e("Error ", it.message.toString())
                        it.printStackTrace()
                        resultDetailUser.value = ResultViewModel.Error(it)
                    } .collect {
                        // Ubah tipe data yang dikirimkan ke resultSuccess.value
                        resultDetailUser.value = ResultViewModel.Success(it)
    
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I have try this code but the error is still exist and the problem is still the same that the result ( Result.Loading )is always return false

Comment: it seems like the issue you are facing is that you are setting the loading state to false in the onCompletion block for both 'getUser' and 'getFollowerUser' functions, this means that after flow is completed, it will always set the loading state to 'false'